# Why is c++ redistibutable not included in Windows Update

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Per se not a problem, but more a "wonder why". Many programs require the use of Visual C++ redistributable. But this is something that HAS to be installed separately. Every single time.  Of course I can include the installer in my installers and execute silently.

But - do anyone know the reason why Microsoft Windows, even the latest versions, do not include VC++ as a feature that's just installed as part of the update program ? Given that Microsoft is behind both.

Comment: There are quite a few. Programs designed with Visual Studio may require a specific version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable to run. The requirement resulted in the installation of a large number of Visual C++ Redistributable packages on Windows PCs. https://community.amd.com/t5/general-discussions/microsoft-ends-visual-c-redistributable-chaos/td-p/85049

Comment: tbh, I've wondered for at least a decade, why something like that is not simply part of the OS. Having to ship a myriad separate & to the end-user seemingly identical libraries just feels like someone made a bad decision early on & it never got fixed.

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm afraid only Microsoft can answer it, so it's off-topic here.

Comment: Lots of official applications are not part of Windows; As to why it’s not an optional feature likely has to do with the fact, Microsoft, has continued to advance the features of Visual C++ thus making it difficult to include it in an ISO that’s static

Comment: @Ramhound - it doesn't need to be static, it just needs to be encapsulated into a 'single package' as far as the end user is concerned & included in OS updates.  It shouldn't even be separated from the main OS itself to the user. Then  the only people who need to be concerned about what version are the devs who rely on it for their apps to work, just like any other OS framework.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Visual C++ was traditionally  updated more often than once a year with Windows 7 and Windows 8 which was updated once every couple years. That means the optional feature would have to be updated that often

Comment: I guess I'm just used to an OS where frameworks are included in the OS or packaged along with a 3rd party app, totally invisible to the end user.

Comment: VC++ typically is invisible, all depends on the installation method, some are more effective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because:

- You can have multiple C++ redistributables installed.
- Some programs need specific versions.  Like really big programs that companies use such as AutoCAD components, etc.

The C++ or any other language redistributable is more associated with a software developer's development environment (e.g. specific version of Visual Studio used to develop and build the executables) than the OS.

It's possible to use environments other than Visual Studio to develop Windows software so that's probably why it's not included--Microsoft is making that the developer's responsibility to get right (which they don't always do) rather than themselves.

Comment: Visual C++ only recently became binary compatible, allowing a single version of (VC++ 2019, VC+ 2022) to be installed which is vastly different to the multiple versions that used to exist in previous editions of VC++

Comment: IMHO this answer does not make much sense: Nowadays where windows is almost never installed from an optical disk (with very limited space), there's absolutely no reason to not include all those runtimes by default instead of forcing developers to ship them with their applications...